# Is it bad practice to pass javascript calculated values to database?

Tags: javascript, database, calculation

Lets assume I have a Form which has 3 input fields:

- *gross amount*
- *value added tax rate*
- *net amount*

The user can fill out the *gross amount* and the *value added tax rate* field. The *net amount* field is set `readonly`.

Now I want to save time and increase permformance by let javascript calculate the *net amount* and fill the required field and pass this value to the database.

The only thing I would check is if the *net amount* field is empty e.g. with [Symfony NotBlank constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html).

Is this bad or bad practice to take the javascript calculated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three dangers here:

- Malicious code injection

This occurs by displaying something a user entered directly back onto the screen or another screen where the user has tampered with the data. For example, a user is asked for their name and types `<script>alert('You got hacked!');</script>` instead of their name. Every user that views their profile will see this code, and if you don't check, it is possible it will execute it on every person's machine that looks.

This would happen if you had a page in the system that displayed the user entered data back without checking it first, in your case perhaps a page that displays the current values from the database.

You can avoid this situation by sanitising what the user types in, or by checking it on the way out of the database.

For your situation though, if you store the values in the database as numbers instead of strings, then you won't have a problem.

- Manipulating values in javascript

You have a much bigger problem though, and that is that you should perform calcuations on the server side. It is possible for the user to manipulate the value of the net amount and send anything they want to the database.

If a user is buying something from an online store, for example, and they add 5 items to their basket costing £1.00 each, then if you calculate the total in javascript (£5.00) and submit and store that, it is possible for the user to edit it and change the total to £0 and get the items for free.

For security you should of course calculate the cost on the server, and use values that you personally retrieve from the database - don't re-use any data sent from the user in the backend because they could also edit the individual item cost to £0 as well.

- Javascript number accuracy

Just as a bonus, you should also be aware that your front end and back end may calculate values differently when you're adding and multiplying numbers together. Consider this code:

`var total = 0.3 - 0.2;`

If you expect total to be 0.1, you're wrong - the answer is something like 0.99999999998.

Javascript doesn't handle floating point numbers very accurately.

Answer (score 5):

Never trust the user. Do everything you can on serverside, even if you've already done it on clientside - especially not a trivially simple calculation like that that will not save you almost any time on serverside.

EDIT: Unless, as Sharky says, you don't actually care about the two other values, and are providing the calculation only as a courtesy to the user. In this case, net value is the real input field - even if it is technically readonly. Validate it and store it as such, and don't even bother transmitting the other two.

Comment: This. @goulashsoup - do you *really* want to store the net amount you received from the user when they can trivially send you any value they want?

Comment: Not anymore, Thanks for your answers!